# Lighting issue when looking at render

Tags: lighting

I am trying to follow along with a tutorial on youtube, however i seem to have an issue with the lighting on the rendered view. does anyone know whats happening here?[image]

Comment: Hello, probably the latest AMD driver that doesn't work, try the previous one or try to active High Quality Normals in Render > Performance

Answer (score 0):

Is your light hided because this looks exactly an issue like that if not try restarting blender and maybe its because you have no light at all
EDIT:I am seeing that there is a sun so my bad :( is this the donut tutorial lol

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this isn't an answer.. to keep the archive as clean as possible, it may be deleted. Nothing personal.